# Deleting consecutive same items in linklist

Tags: java

So I have to write a function to delete Node with consecutive same items. Like: {1,1,1,2,3,3,4} becomes: {1,2,3,4}
I have written the following code, cant figure out whats wrong with it. It works for the first few items  only.

```
public void deleterepetitive()
    {
        Node itr = head;
        Node itrfront=itr.getNext(); 

        while(itr.getNext()!=null)
        {

            if(itr.getItem()==itrfront.getItem())
            {
                itr.setNext(itrfront.getNext());
            }
            itr = itr.getNext();
            itrfront = itrfront.getNext();

        }
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Remove duplicate entries in the doubly linked list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26823759/remove-duplicate-entries-in-the-doubly-linked-list)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the line `itrfront = itrfront.getNext();` to `itrfront = itr.getNext();` within the while loop. I guess your code breaks after first duplicate omission.

Change the if block as below:(we need check the new next item and not skip it.)

```
if(itr.getItem()==itrfront.getItem())
{
   itrfront = itrfront.getnext();       
   itr.setNext(itrfront);
   continue;       
}
```

Earlier you code was

**1st iteration:**

```
1     1     1    1    1   2     3     3     4
^     ^ 
ITR  NExt
```

duplicate fond so remove node

**2nd iteration:**

```
1     1     1    1   2     3     3     4
      ^     ^ 
     ITR   NExt
```

Answer (score 0):

there are many ways to do this.

i find either stepping through the list from the bottom (starting at the N'th item and iterating back to zero'th item) or taking the collection and inserting it into a Set collection to force the collapse of identical values also works.

cheers

Comment: could you take a look at my code snippet? I don't know what is wrong with my logic

Answer (score 0):

You're not incrementing your iterators correctly, you want itrfront to always be in front of itr, but its actually on top of it:
Let **itr** be : ^, **itrfront** be: A, and **itr.getNext()** be: n, this is what's occurring:

```
  n
1 1 1 2 2 2 2 3
^ A

    n
1 1 1 2 2 2 2 3
^ A

      n
1 *1* 1 2 2 2 2 3
      ^ 
      A

        n
1 *1* 1 2 2 2 2 3
      ^ 
      A

        n
1 *1* 1 2 2 2 2 3
        ^ 
        A
```

where the *1* means garbage collected

What you want to do is something like this:

```
while(itr.getNext()!=null)
{
    while(itr.getItem()==itrFront.getItem())
    {
        itrfront = itrfront.getNext();
    }
    itr.setNext(itrfront);
    itr = itr.getNext();
    itrfront = itr.getNext();
}
```